# Using icons sprite sheet in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

I am trying to convert a **.yaml** style file to QGIS style file.

The yaml file has a sprite sheet for displaying icons. I did a little search on the Internet but couldn't find anything useful. Below image shows the sprite sheet

[image: Example]

One way is to convert sprite sheet to separate icons but i don't want to do that. Is there a way to use sprite sheet as it is in QGIS?